# Change knockout values before posting them to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Let's say I have a VM like this (price1 to price100)...

```
var Item = {
    price1: ko.observable(),
    price2: ko.observable(),
    price3: ko.observable(),
    ...
    ...
    price100: ko.observable(),
    name: ko.observable()
}
```

But before posting it to my server, I need to replace all dots with commmas in every single price but not the "name" variable.

I don't want to change the field itself. I use ko.toJS(Item) ... so it's this result I want to change without manually going through all prices.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going all the way to JSON, then you could do something like described here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html

You can add a `toJSON` function to `Item.prototype` something like:

```
Item.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    //if calling ko.toJSON this will already be a "clean" object, but if calling JSON.stringify, then it would not, so get a clean version anyways
    var clean = ko.toJS(this);

    for (var prop in clean) {
        if (clean.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop.indexOf("price") > -1) {
              clean[prop] = clean[prop].toString().replace(".", ",");
        }
    }

    return clean;
};
```

Then, when you do `ko.toJSON(myItem)` it will do the replacement.

If you do not want to go all the way to JSON, then you would basically want to do the same thing directly.  So, you could really call the `toJSON` function above and get back your clean object. `var clean = myItem.toJSON();`

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/zX7Ld/